# stuck while installing packages. npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for sockjs-client@0.0.0-unreleasable

Tags: node.js

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with 
lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for 
lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for sockjs-client@0.0.0- 
unreleasable
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are 
requesting 
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'shoe'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2018-08-27T12_19_24_084Z-debug.log
```

i got this Error While installing packages it dont let me install packages please Help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: may be by name **unreleasable** we can guess that it is not for public.So you can try `npm install sockjs-client` if that do your work.

Comment: @RajanLagah it also gives me this: -  Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

Comment: I just ran `npm install sockjs-client` and this package got installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try out below steps to resolve that error

step 1 - remove your node_modules folder

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

step 2 -

> npm cache clean

step 3 -

> sudo apt-get install build-essential

step 4 -  remove your package-lock.json and install node modules again.

> npm install

(if there is EACCESS error comes then try with sudo command.)

Comment: Life saver solution ++

Answer (score 8):

One cause of “code ETARGET” “notarget No matching version found for express@4.17.1” (when running `npm update`) is [`prefer-offline=true`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#prefer-offline) in npm configuration, which causes npm (specifically [npm-registry-cache](https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-fetch/blob/v12.0.0/lib/index.js#L204-L209)) to never update its HTTP cache if an existing resource was fetched.  `prefer-offline` can be useful to speed up `npm ci`, but if you use it for `npm update`, then `npm`/[pacote](https://github.com/npm/pacote/blob/main/lib/registry.js) will cache [package metadata requests a.k.a. packuments](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md#getpackage) (e.g. GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express) forever and will not be able to update to the newest version. So if you have any of [`prefer-offline=true`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#prefer-offline), [`cache-min=9999`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#cache-min), [`offline=true`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#offline) set in the npm CLI flags, [environment variables](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#environment-variables), or [npmrc files](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#npmrc-files) (`/path/to/my/project/.npmrc`, `~/.npmrc`, etc.), then don’t forget to remove them when performing `npm update` and `npm install`.

So the takeaways as far as I can tell are:

- If you use `--prefer-offline` when you run `npm install`, `npm update`, `npm outdated` etc., then occasionally remove `--prefer-offline` or `npm cache clean`.
- Use `npm ci --prefer-offline` instead of `npm install --prefer-offline` when doing continuous builds

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. In local I update some packages then I run `npm install` and the package-lock is updated, then I push the changes and in my ci pipeline where I'm using `npm install --prefer-offline`, I get the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Vahid Basically remove `--prefer-offline` from `npm install --prefer-offline`, clean the `~/.npm` cache using `npm cache clean`, or switch to `npm ci --prefer-offline`

Answer (score 5):

I solved the issue by

1. Delete node-modules folder
2. Deleting the `package-lock.json` file
3. Run `npm install`
4. Now Run `npm start`

Answer (score 3):

This might help someone This is how I solve the issue of my npm dependency conflicts: I look at the conflict error message and update it to the latest version.

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps vite@latest
npm install --legacy-peer-deps @vitejs/plugin-vue@latest
npm install --legacy-peer-deps laravel-vite-plugin@latest
```

That works for me

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, but in my case the library is a in house library which is hosted in a nexus repository. If this is the case, please check if the version specified in the `package.json` file is available in the nexus repository.