# No matching version found for react-router-dom@2.1.3

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for react-router-dom@^2.1.3.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-14T11_35_07_149Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stuck while installing packages. npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for sockjs-client@0.0.0-unreleasable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039375/stuck-while-installing-packages-npm-err-notarget-no-matching-version-found-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clearing the cache and re install again

`npm cache clean --force`

then

`npm install`

Answer (score 0):

tried this but it's throwing these errors!!

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\Offices\Office Sator-it\Projects\React project\FreseniusPortal - Copy\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
and other errors

Comment: Responses to comments should not be given as "Answer". You could edit the question and incorporate the feedback from comments.

Answer (score 0):

`react-router-dom@^2.1.3.` try to remove the last dot from the the line

```
react-router-dom@^2.1.3
```